# Reverse engineer a PS-EXE file

Tags: mips

I'm playing currently a CTF, i was asked to find the flag in PX-EXE file. Its architecture is MIPS. When i type `file` command in the terminal i get the following:

```
Sony Playstation executable PC=0x8005d448, .text=[0x8005d000,0x15800], Stack=0x801ffff0, (Europe area)
```

Any ideas or helpful links please ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

IDA Pro [supports](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/file_formats/) the PSX-EXE file format.